# grid layout with square images (overflow hidden)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I'm busy with a grid layout with images in each div of the grid. But I want to have every image as a square so all the overflow must be hidden. My only problem is, the width is set as '20%' how do I get the height to be the exact width of that div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `padding-bottom:100%`

This technique is very useful to keep the aspect ratio of objects (squared ratio in your case). The only drawback is that the `div` must be set as `position:relative` and inside you must have elements with `position:absolute`.

Comment: I don't want to do anything with the aspect ratio. I want the parent div to be a square so the overflow of the image in that div needs to be hidden. But I don't know how to set the height of the parent div.

Comment: "square" is an aspect ratio. The aspect ratio is 1:1. Sorry I forgot to mention that the content must be absolute for this technique to work. I am updating the post

Comment: Okay, I still can't figure it out. I've made a jsFiddle, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/wSbnj/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wSbnj/2/ The padding:100% only works when the width of the element is also 100%. In this case, you have to set the padding bottom the same as the width.

Comment: don't forget to mark this as answered :) or vote up if you yet can't

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Carlos Martinez, this is what I needed:
http://jsfiddle.net/wSbnj/2/

```
div#image {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    border:1px solid red;
    position:relative;
    width:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div#image img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
​
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="image"><img src="http://static.zara.net/photos//2012/I/0/2/p/5618/655/802/5618655802_1_1_3.jpg?timestamp=1350490400442"></div>
</div>
```

​